# Wordpress %postname% permalinks break static homepage (301)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

so I am having this issue for a while now, and I cannot seem to find a fitting solution.

Whenever I enable %postname% permalinks, my static homepage `https://example.com/xy` stops working and delivers 301 “site is not redirecting properly” errors, while any other posts or pages on the site redirect properly, example `https://example.com/xy/about-us` works.

If I revert back to plain links, I have no issues.
Two things that I’ve noticed are, if I add “index.php” at the end of the homepage it will load again, example `https://example.com/xy/index.php`.

%postname% permalinks also work if I set site url inside a wp-config.php like this

`define( ‘WP_HOME’, ‘http://example.com/xy’ );`

`define( ‘WP_SITEURL’, ‘http://example.com/xy’ );`

However I am required to keep site url path relative, so this is not a desired fix.

I’ve tried disabling all plugins and changing theme to default to no avail.
I've enabled AllowOverride for my root directory.
I have mod rewrite enabled in apache, my .htaccess is generated by WP and looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xy/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /xy/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: it looks like you have /xy/ sub-folder where you have installed WP and does your site works when you add slash in end https://example.com/xy/     

Recheck your htaccess from your code where is opening <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> directive?

Comment: Adding slash returned same results, my .htacess also seems to be properly configured with mod_rewrite.c. In the end I worked around it, by editing functions.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I worked around this issue by adding following into my functions.php

```
function disable_front_page_redirects($redirect_url) {
        if( is_front_page() ) {
                $redirect_url = false;
        }

        return $redirect_url;
}

add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'disable_front_page_redirects' );
```